# Extract info from a text file and use it in a command in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, awk, centos, ifs

I am trying to extract info from a .list file called 'accounts.list'
and use the extracted info in a command line operation in CentOS 7. I know there is a simple solution but I cannot for the life of me find it.

So the file has each line listed in the following format:

```
John Smith | jsmith
Jane Doe | jdoe
```

What I need to do is add users with the information from each line. So for example I would like to add each part to a variable, and then use the variable in a adduser command:

```
fn=John
ln=Smith
un=jsmith

useradd -c "$fn $ln" $un
```

So I need to go through each line and extract that info, add the user, and then continue on to the next line. I want to do this in the simplest way possible, but nothing I've tried has worked, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that shell assignments are not usually prefixed with a `$`; you almost certainly wanted `fn=John`.  As written, if `fn=XYZ`, then `$fn=John` sets `$XYZ` to `John`.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, yes I was writing it incorrectly, I'm still very new to shell commands (as I'm sure you can tell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r fn ln ignore un; do useradd -c "$fn $ln" "$un"; done <accounts.list
```

Or, if you prefer commands spread over multiple lines:

```
while read -r fn ln ignore un
do
    useradd -c "$fn $ln" "$un"
done <accounts.list
```

#### How it works

Each line of your file has four fields: the first name (fn), the last name (ln), the vertical bar, the username (un).  The command `read` reads from the input file line-by-line and assigns these four fields to the variables `fn`, `ln`, `ignore`, and `un`.

Comment: Thank you John, you won't believe how similar of a solution I was trying but I was doing a few things wrong. Yours worked like a charm though and was nice and clean :)